# adding rel="nofollow" while saving data

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I have my application to allow users to write comments on my website. Its working fine. I also have tool to insert their weblinks in it. I feel good with contents with their own weblinks.

Now i want to add rel="nofollow" to every links on content that they have been written.

I would like to add rel="nofollow" using php i.e while saving data.

So what's a simple method to add rel="nofollow" or updated rel="someother" with rel="someother nofollow" using php

a nice example will be much efficient

Comment: You could also use HTMLPurifier with `$config->set("HTML.Nofollow", TRUE);` albeit you'll have to reallow all the other rel= attributes first (strips everything per default).

Comment: What markup language are you using for the comments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regexs really aren't the best tool for dealing with HTML, especially when PHP has a pretty good HTML parser built in.

This code will handle adding `nofollow` if the `rel` attribute is already populated.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor) { 
    $rel = array(); 

    if ($anchor->hasAttribute('rel') AND ($relAtt = $anchor->getAttribute('rel')) !== '') {
       $rel = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($relAtt));
    }

    if (in_array('nofollow', $rel)) {
      continue;
    }

    $rel[] = 'nofollow';
    $anchor->setAttribute('rel', implode(' ', $rel));
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/VJXTutgN).

The resulting HTML is in `$dom->saveHTML()`. Except it will wrap it with `html`, `body` elements, etc, so use this to extract just the HTML you entered...

```
$html = '';

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $element) {
    $html .= $dom->saveXML($element, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}

echo $html;
```

If you have >= PHP 5.3, replace `saveXML()` with `saveHTML()` and drop the second argument.

#### Example

This HTML...

```
<a href="">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="hello there">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="nofollow">hello</a>
```

...is converted into...

```
<a href="" rel="nofollow">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="nofollow">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="hello there nofollow">hello</a>

<a href="" rel="nofollow">hello</a>
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Looks fine to me (although adding an example how to output the result would be nice). +1

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, I guess someone doesn't like me :) Update coming with example :)

Comment: @alex: Tried to use `saveHTML()` But getting warning that `saveHTML()` takes only one argument. Also getting some junk characters on my page (check second paragraph). Any idea why?

Comment: @Sisir If using `saveHTML()`, drop the second argument.

Comment: Amazing. I've apparently been stuck in history for years and have been using regex all this time. It's time for me to leave the past and enter the realm of DOM.

Comment: @Pamela Enjoy! It does make these things much more easier in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Good Alex. If it is in the form of a function it is more useful. So I made it below:

```
function add_no_follow($str){ 
  $dom = new DOMDocument;

  $dom->loadHTML($str);

  $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach($anchors as $anchor) { 
      $rel = array(); 

      if ($anchor->hasAttribute('rel') AND ($relAtt = $anchor->getAttribute('rel')) !== '') {
         $rel = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($relAtt));
      }

      if (in_array('nofollow', $rel)) {
        continue;
      }

      $rel[] = 'nofollow';
      $anchor->setAttribute('rel', implode(' ', $rel));
  }

  $dom->saveHTML();

  $html = '';

  foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $element) {
      $html .= $dom->saveXML($element, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
  }

  return $html;      
}
```

Use as follows :

```
  $str = "Some content with link Some content  ... ";

 $str = add_no_follow($str);
```

Comment: Wrapping an existing answer with a function isn't much of an answer.

Comment: Regarding your flag .. when in Rome ... :)

Comment: It might now be a answer, but it is a improvement and I've found it useful, so thanks both of you!

Comment: I think my answer encapsulate unwanted complexity. And I thought it is more appropriate to give it as a separate answer without editing in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848273/1303123) and made it into a function that makes links nofollow and open in a new tab/window (and added UTF-8 support). I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works (constructive input is welcome):

```
function nofollow_new_window($str)
{
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor)
    { 
    $rel = array(); 

    if ($anchor->hasAttribute('rel') AND ($relAtt = $anchor->getAttribute('rel')) !== '') {
       $rel = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($relAtt));
        }

    if (in_array('nofollow', $rel)) {
      continue;
        }

    $rel[] = 'nofollow';
    $anchor->setAttribute('rel', implode(' ', $rel));

    $target = array(); 

    if ($anchor->hasAttribute('target') AND ($relAtt = $anchor->getAttribute('target')) !== '') {
       $target = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($relAtt));
        }

    if (in_array('_blank', $target)) {
      continue;
        }

    $target[] = '_blank';
    $anchor->setAttribute('target', implode(' ', $target));
    }

$str = utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
return $str;
}
```

Simply use the function like this:

```
$str = '<html><head></head><body>fdsafffffdfsfdffff dfsdaff flkklfd aldsfklffdssfdfds <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></body></html>';

$str = nofollow_new_window($str);

echo $str;
```